# Jekyll does not render md tables correctly if the table contains liquid tags

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I am using a custom Liquid tag that, when building my site from .md files with Jekyll, replaces the value in the tag with a corresponding `<span>` element from a predefined list (similarly to how it works with custom Docbook entities).

The problem I've encountered is as follows: if this tag is in a table written with Markdown syntax, then this table will not render as such; instead, it transforms into a `<p>...</p>` element whose textContent is, well, the original markdown-formatted table as plain text. The `<span>` elements substituted by my Liquid tag are rendered correctly.

If I enclose the md table in {%raw%}{%endraw%}, then the table is rendered correctly except that, obviously, my custom tag is ignored.

Here's the Liquid tag I am using:

```rb
module Jekyll
    class EntityHandler < Liquid::Tag

        @@dictionary = {}
        file = File.open("./assets/definitions/entities.txt")
        strings = file.readlines
        strings.each do |s|
            key, value = s.split("|")
            @@dictionary[key] = value.to_s
        end

        file.close

        def initialize(name, input, tokens)
            super
            @input = input.strip
        end

        def render(context)

            dictionary = @@dictionary

            if dictionary.has_key?(@input.to_s)
                output = dictionary.fetch_values(@input)
            else
                output = "<span class='btn-false'>ERROR: entity not found</span>"
            end

            return output
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('ent', Jekyll::EntityHandler)
```

When used anywhere in .md files, `{% ent X %}` renders as `<span>X</span>`, which is what I expect. However, it does not work with .md tables. Thus, if I make a table like this:

```md
| Cell one | Cell two |
| === | === |
| Cell three | {% ent X %} |
```

it returns:

```html
<p>| Cell one | Cell two || === | === || Cell three | <span>X</span> <!-- actual entity value --> |</p>
```

instead of a `<table/>`.